# Turning a text file to multiple arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to convert a text file with multiple strings into multiple arrays but the code printed them in one array. the code as follows

```
File file = new File("C://Users//DELL//Desktop//PSOFS+10CV//AA.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>() ;
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    lines.add(scan.nextLine());
}

String[] array = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

My text file like this

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0][1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0][0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0][1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1][0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

The above code give me the following result

```
[[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0] , [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0] , [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0] ]
```

where all the strings are printed in one array while i need them in multiple arrays rather one.
thanks all

Comment: You are creating a single array (`array`) that is populated with arrays (`new String[0]`).

Comment: so how can I populate each array with only one array

Answer (score 0):

If your text is all in one line (as your example text suggests), then `nextLine()` puts that line into one String.
You have to split your text after reading it into the parts you want, like

```java
String line=scan.nextLine();
Matcher matcher=new Pattern("(\\[[^\\]]+\\])").matcher(line);
while(matcher.find())
 lines.add(matcher.group(0))
```